# tcpdump -G option for rotation

Tags: tcpdump

I would like to rotate the tcp dump saving every 100mS.
Hence I am trying the following option:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -G 0.1 -w '.pcap'
```

This dumps all the incoming data into file and do not rotate every 100mS. Could someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It creates file `.pcap` which it's hidden and since you are not using the timestamp to name the files to generate, it overwrites to the same file `.pcap` every time.

accepted timestamp format can be specified in known formats by ["strftime(3)"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

one example like:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -G 0.1 -w %m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s.pcap
```

please note that `0.1`seconds you specified to `-G` option less than a second will not grantee that all captured packets will be written to the corresponding file, since there is no way in `strftime(3)` to define milliseconds formatting, so as long as traffic captured for age of a second those will still overwritten  to the previous matched filename specified in `-w ...` option.

so change `-G 0.1` to minimum 1second to don't miss any packets to be saved in files.

**Important:** *Be warned about what timestamp you choice for formatting/rotating*; for example with above timestamp since it generates a unique timestamp for a lifetime, so files will be generated until you have a free disk-space *on the path you ran the tcpdump* command.

choosing timestamps like `%H-%M-%S.pcap` will rotate for a day (24hours) and start overwrite to the oldest file for new day. so this timestamp plus with `-G 1` would be your better choice to having 24hours rotation every seconds.